# Gulp dest path has full src path location appended, instead of just the dest property

Tags: svg, stream, gulp

When I am doing gulp.src... followed by some svg color transformation followed by gulp.dest, the destination path gets appended the source path altough that shouldn't be... I use gulp4 and ("gulp-recolor-svg") plugin... (and a debug plugin to see src paths of streams)

```
return gulp
                .src(path.join(settings.folder_src + 'sprite/svg/', folder, '*.svg'))
                .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn:'}))
                .pipe(recolorsvg.Replace(from_colors, to_colors))
                .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn2:'}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.folder_build + "sprite/recolored", { extends: true , base: __dirname}))
                .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn3:'}))
```

Output:

```
[14:42:16] unicorn: src\sprite\svg\to_black\guided_tour.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn2: src\sprite\svg\to_black\guided_tour.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn: 1 item
[14:42:16] unicorn2: 1 item
[14:42:16] unicorn: src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-left.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn2: src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-left.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn: src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-right.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn2: src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-right.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn: 2 items
[14:42:16] unicorn2: 2 items
[14:42:16] unicorn3: build\sprite\recolored\src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-left.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn3: build\sprite\recolored\src\sprite\svg\to_black\guided_tour.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn3: 1 item
[14:42:16] unicorn3: build\sprite\recolored\src\sprite\svg\to_white\gallery-arrow-right.svg
[14:42:16] unicorn3: 2 items
[14:42:16] Finished 'recolor_svg' after 159 ms
```

However, this is only in the dev environment, in production its the same code and it behaves normally, I don't understand why, because .env settings are nearly exactly the same... I have some webpack settings but those are nothing special and dont affect any paths or chunks etc...

Comment: I don't see `{ extends: true , base: __dirname}` listed as options for gulp.dest: see https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest#options `base` is an option for gulp.src though.

Comment: yeah, well anyways I fixed it by adding `.src(path.join(__dirname + '/' +   settings.folder_src + 'sprite/svg/', folder, '*.svg'))` but I still don't know why because its the same path in src as before..

Comment: might it be that gulp somehow remembers the previously set src or dest path in a pipeline chain and uses that new path for the next functions in the chain?